# Shiny: Render Outputs when hidden

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I am trying to render a few outputs in a shiny application that are contained within a `shinyjs::hidden` section upon the application running rather than once the section is visible.

**EDIT**: I had the app set up incorrectly in the original example so have changed it.

I want to be able to run the reactive statement before running the final observe to change the UI from the Alpha text to the Beta text and plot. Ideally this would mean in the console would see `"Done plotting"` before `"Observe run"`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  div(id = "before-content", h3("Aux Text Alpha")),
  shinyjs::hidden(
    div(
      id = "after-content", 
      h1("Aux Text Beta"), 
      plotOutput("text")
    )
  )
)

server <- function( session,input, output) {

  in_plot <- reactive({
    Sys.sleep(3)
    print("Done plotting")
    plot(iris)
  })

  output$text <- renderPlot({
    in_plot()
  })

  observe({
    print("Observe run")
    hide("before-content")
    show("after-content")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

An alternative would be to have a layer over what is classed as the hidden section but am not too sure on how that is accomplished.

Answer (score 0):

You can `hide` it in the reactive, like so:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  actionButton("button", "Click me"),
  plotOutput("text")
)

server <- function( session,input, output) {

  in_plot <- reactive({
    hide("text")
    Sys.sleep(3)
    print("Done plotting")
    plot(iris)
  })

  output$text <- renderPlot({
    in_plot()
  })

  observeEvent(input$button, {
    show("text")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Apologies, I've realised that I have set up the example slightly wrong. Will update and hopefully makes it clearer. Thanks for the suggestion though!